# Limit of a sequence of functions over a convergent sequence of points in its domain

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

$(f_n)$ is a sequence of continuous, real valued functions on a metric space $M$.

It converges pointwise to a **continuous** function $f$.

Suppose that $(y_m)$ is a sequence of points in $M$, and it converges to point $y\in M$.

Then, $lim_{y_m\to\ y}[lim_{n\to\infty} (f_n(y_m))] = lim_{n\to\infty}[lim_{y_m\to\ y} (f_n(y_m))] = f(y)$

I think it follows from continuity of $f$ and the functions $f_n$, and the definitions of those limits.

Is this right?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy, but the function to which the sequence of functions in this example converges (pointwise) to is not continuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have written is correct.  As written, $\lim_{y_m\to\ y}[\lim_{n\to\infty} (f_n(y_m))]$ appears to be an [iterated limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit), meaning that you first take the inside limit, and then you take the outside limit.  So we say "first, fix $y_m$.  Now what is $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(y_m)$?" For whatever $y_m$ we have, that is equal to $f(y_m)$ because $f_n$ converge to $f$ pointwise. Now we put that into our double limit:
$$
\lim_{y_m\to y}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(y_m)
=\lim_{y_m\to y}f(y_m)
=f(y),
$$
where now we know how to take the outer limit.

Do note, though, that this is not the same as the double limit
$$
\lim_{\substack{y_m\to y\\n\to\infty}}f_n(y_m).
$$
There is no reason in general for the double limit to be equal to the iterated limits (or even for the two iterated limits to be equal! Although they are in this case) This is what is being discussed in HyperPro's answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you! That distinction is imperative to what I was saying. I understood HyperPro's point as well, I just assumed that what I had written was not what I was trying to say, 
the iterative limit is defined as the double limit and the definition I was using was just incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong, you need uniform convergence of $f_n$ for this.

You have to show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ with $$\Vert f_n(y_n)-f(y)\Vert\leq\epsilon$$
for $n>N$ and you want to somehow use
$$\Vert f_n(y_n)-f(y)\Vert\leq \Vert f_n(y_n)-f(y_n)\Vert+\Vert f(y_n)+f(y)\Vert$$

Now consider an $\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is continues there exists a $N_1$ with $$\Vert f(y_n)-f(y)\Vert\leq\epsilon/2$$
But now there is a problem. You won't find a $N_2$ with
\begin{equation}
\Vert f_n(y_m)-f(y_m)\Vert<\epsilon/2
\end{equation}
for all $m,n>N_2$. Because for every $y_m$ you might need a new $N_{y_m}$, so that last inequality would only be true for an $n>\max\{N_2,N_{y_m}\}$ and only that fixed $y_m$. Due to that you can't even use the same index for $f_n$ and $y_m$.
Uniform convergence instead of only pointwise would ensure the existence of such an $N_2$! (and in this case you could justify to use the same index for $f$ and $y$)

To sum up, you do not only need uniform convergence for $f$ being continuous. Even if $f$ is continuous by assumpten you do need uniform convergence!

Comment: Thanks! I mean that the $y_m$ and $f_n$ are considered independently, one at a time to evaluate the limits one after the other.